# Need help in extracting values from Json for Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

My Json is like below, I want to extract json for all the "**code**" values and put them with comma separated. **I have almost 250 code values and want them like this

> RFI027,RFI037,RFI407,RFI055,RFI457,RFI677,RFI068,RFI086

```
{
   "totalDocs":202,
   "recordBatchSize":224,
   "listingType":31,
   "currentPageNo":1,
   "recordStartFrom":18,
   "columnHeader":[
      {
         "id":"0",
         "fieldName":"commId",
         "isCustomAttributeColumn":false,
         "isActive":false
      },
      {
         "id":"24264704",
         "function":"",
         "funParams":"",
         "wrapData":"",
      },
       {
         "code":"RFI027",
         "noOfActions":0,
         "observationId":0         
      },
      {
         "code":"RFI037",
         "noOfActions":0,
         "observationId":0         
      },
      {
         "code":"RFI407",
         "noOfActions":0,
         "observationId":0         
      },      
      {
         "code":"RFI055",
         "noOfActions":0,
         "observationId":0         
      },
      {
         "code":"RFI457",
         "noOfActions":0,
         "observationId":0         
      },
      {
         "code":"RFI677",
         "noOfActions":0,
         "observationId":0         
      },
      {
         "code":"RFI068",
         "noOfActions":0,
         "observationId":0         
      },      
      {
         "code":"RFI086",
         "noOfActions":0,
         "observationId":0         
      },
   ],
   "sortField":"updated",
   "sortFieldType":"timestamp",
   "sortOrder":"desc",
   "editable":true,
   "isIncludeSubFolder":true,
   "totalListData":0
}
```

**I tried with $..code in Jmeter Json Extractor but it returns only one Value.** but I want output like **RFI027,RFI037,RFI407,RFI055,RFI457,RFI677,RFI068,RFI086**. As I want to pass all values in another request. **I have tried with 0,1,2,3 and -1 match no. but it returns only one value, while for -1 it returns ${ref_formCode1}.** *Appreciate your help. Thank you in advanced.*

[image]

**Edit:**

After implementing `JSR223 post-processer` It shows blank field. Here are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `JSR223 post-processer` using the following code, meanwhile notice there are few syntactical errors in your JSON,

Add the `JSR223 post-processer` to your request and this will do your ask

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData());
def CodeFile = '';

response.columnHeader.code.each {
  Code->if (Code == null) {}
  else {
    CodeFile += Code + ','  //this will have your code but there will be ',' at the last
  }
}

def CodeFileList = CodeFile.subSequence(0, CodeFile.length() - 1) // this will remove the last ,
log.info('CodeFile:' + CodeFileList)
vars.put("CodeList",CodeFileList)
```

[image]

**If the code value is inside the data**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData());
def CodeFile = '';

response.data.code.each {Code->
  if (Code == null) {}
  else {
    CodeFile += Code + ','  //this will have your code but there will be ',' at the last
  }
}

def CodeFileList = CodeFile.subSequence(0, CodeFile.length() - 1) // this will remove the last ,
log.info('CodeList:' + CodeFileList)
vars.put("CodeList",CodeFileList)
```

Usage: Inside request body

[image]

[image]

Inside the request URL

[image]

[image]

In another controller,

[image]

[image]

==========

After edit in the main question:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jyoti Prakash. How do I use 'CodeFileList' in my next http request as input?  I have used like ${CodeFileList} this in request but in response it passes the same ${CodeFileList} instead of values.

Comment: Please try to use ${__groovy(vars.get('CodeFileList'),)}

Comment: I have passed ${__groovy(vars.get('CodeFileList'),)} but it passes blank here.

Comment: Could you please paste the request method and how you are using it ?

Comment: Added few screenshot for reference

Comment: Hey Jyoti Prakash, Thanks for the edits. appreciate your help & efforts.  I have edited my question with Screenshots. you can check what I am missing.

Comment: Is it in the same thread group or different thread group ?

Comment: Its in same thread group. Its like, Request-1 --> JSR223 Postprocessor Then Reques-2 > Fetch that value.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need to:

1. Set "Match No" to `-1`
2. Tick `Compute concatenation var` box

[image]

It will give you the `${ref_formCode1_ALL}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding all codes matched by you [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query separated by commas:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)